# MATLAB Simulink Changing Initial Condition

Tags: matlab, simulink, ode

I am trying to solve the following in Simulink

```
Y’=2y/t with y(1) = 1
```

I have the following drawn:
[image]

I chose “external” initial condition hoping I could figure out a way to y(0) to y(1) but I can’t seem to figure that out.

Comment: What if you shift the time scale? `y'(t)=2y(t)/(1+t)` with `y(0)=1`?

Comment: If y(1)=1, what output do you expect in the first simulation step at t=0?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sure but I don't want to do modify the original ODE every single time I have different type of initial conditions. There has to be an easier way.

Comment: You could also just "switch on" the initial condition at `t=1`, `y(t) = u(t-1) + int(0,t, 2*y(s)/s )`, `u` being the unit ramp function. This works here as the equation is linear with no forcing, the zero solution is the state of being "switched off".